# TableView not scrolling when created programmatically

Tags: ios, scroll, tableview

I have a tableView created programmatically and scrolling does not work. Selection works fine, but no scrolling. Any suggestions?
My code below:

.m

```
[dialogView addSubview:dialogTableView];

CGRect dialogTableViewFrame = CGRectMake(10, 150, 260, 300);
dialogTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:dialogTableViewFrame style: UITableViewStylePlain];

dialogTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
dialogTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
dialogTableView.delegate = self;
dialogTableView.dataSource = self;

[dialogTableView reloadData];

[dialogView addSubview:dialogTableView];
```

.h

```
@interface MapsViewController : UIViewController <GMSMapViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {

UIView *dialogView;
UITableView *dialogTableView;
UIScrollView *dialogScrollView;



}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *dialogView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *dialogTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *dialogScrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *people;
```

Comment: what is the result of `[dialogTableView contentSize]` ?

Comment: Content Size: 260.000000 x 0.000000 (!!!!?)

Comment: Try to remove the autoresizingMask I'm not sure if it's needed here.

Comment: nothing heppened... =/

Comment: It seems to be a google maps mapview interference. once I remove the mapview, tableview starts to scroll! Now I try to figure out why its heppening...

Comment: solved. I inserted the mapview as a subview and the interference went out. thanks folks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the tableView's bounce property to `YES`.

```
dialogTableView.bounces = YES;
dialogTableView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
```

From experience, if these are set to NO it can prevent the tableView from scrolling.

Comment: thanks for the help but it didnt work! scrolling still frozen :( tableview selection is working fine.